# Left Join same table multiple times getting only the max value each join

Tags: sql

I have the following query which returns multiple rows per join but I need to return only the row with the highest id

Any ideas how I can do this without sub-queries?

```
SELECT cp.RefId, work.PhoneNumber AS work, work.id AS work_id, home.PhoneNumber AS home, home.id AS home_id
FROM Contacts cp
LEFT JOIN OtherPhoneNumber work ON cp.ZoneId = work.ZoneId AND work.PhoneNumber_Type = 'W' AND work.OwnerType = 'C' AND work.OwnerRefId = cp.RefId
LEFT JOIN OtherPhoneNumber home ON cp.ZoneId = home.ZoneId AND home.PhoneNumber_Type = 'H' AND home.OwnerType = 'C' AND home.OwnerRefId = cp.RefId
WHERE cp.ZoneId = '123123'
```

This returns something like:

```
RefId       work                work_id    home             home_id
QWERTY1234  01234523423         1739092    01234563232      1818181
QWERTY1234  01234523423267196   1739093    01234563232      1818181
```

I only want:

```
RefId       work                work_id    home             home_id
QWERTY1234  01234523423267196   1739093    01234563232      1818181
```

Comment: Then add group by clause in your query

Comment: The trouble is, this is a simplified version of a bigger query and mssql requires me to group on every column... not so easy to maintain.

Comment: The answer you accepted uses subqueries (which you asked to avoid). Did you look at other answers as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to extract the ids for the home and work numbers, and then join back to the original tables:

```
SELECT cp.RefId, work.PhoneNumber AS work, work.id AS work_id,
       home.PhoneNumber AS home, home.id AS home_id
FROM Contacts cp LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT o..OwnerRefId, o.zoneId,
             MAX(CASE WHEN o..PhoneNumber_Type = 'W' THEN w.id END) as workid,
             MAX(CASE WHEN o..PhoneNumber_Type = 'H' THEN w.id END) as homeid
      FROM OtherPhoneNumber o
      WHERE w.OwnerType = 'C'
      GROUP BY o.OwnerRefId, o..zoneId
     ) wh
     ON cp.RefId = w.OwnerRefId LEFT JOIN
     OtherPhoneNumber work
     ON work.id = wh.workid LEFT JOIN
     OtherPhoneNumber home
     ON home.id = wh.homeid 
WHERE cp.ZoneId = '123123';
```

EDIT:

In SQL Server, you can do this using `OUTER APPLY`:

```
select cp.RefId, work.PhoneNumber AS work, work.id AS work_id, 
       home.PhoneNumber AS home, home.id AS home_id
from Contacts cp outer apply
     (select top 1 o.*
      from OtherPhoneNumber o
      where o.PhoneNumber_Type = 'W' AND o.OwnerType = 'C' AND
            o.OwnerRefId = cp.RefId AND o.ZoneId = cp.ZoneId
      order by o.id desc
     ) work outer apply
     (select top 1 o.*
      from OtherPhoneNumber o
      where o.PhoneNumber_Type = 'H' AND o.OwnerType = 'C' AND
            o.OwnerRefId = cp.RefId AND o.ZoneId = cp.ZoneId
      order by o.id desc
     ) home 
where cp.ZoneId = '123123';
```

This is probably the fastest approach, with the right indexes:   `Contacts(ZoneId, RefId)` and `OtherPhoneNumber(ZoneId, OwnerRefId, PhoneNumber_Type, OwnerType, id)`.

Comment: OP asked for a solution without subqueries.

Comment: I did ask for a solution without subqueries but that's because I was unable to join a subquery on the refid equaling the ownerrefid. This solution allows for that, so it does actually solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay you can try this -

```
;WITH myCTE
AS 
(
    SELECT
        cp.RefId
        ,work.PhoneNumber AS work
        ,work.id AS work_id
        ,home.PhoneNumber AS home
        ,home.id AS home_id
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cp.RefId, work.PhoneNumber, work.id, home.PhoneNumber, home.id ORDER BY cp.RefId) AS RowNum
    FROM Contacts cp
    LEFT JOIN OtherPhoneNumber work
        ON cp.ZoneId = work.ZoneId
        AND work.PhoneNumber_Type = 'W'
        AND work.OwnerType = 'C'
        AND work.OwnerRefId = cp.RefId
    LEFT JOIN OtherPhoneNumber home
        ON cp.ZoneId = home.ZoneId
        AND home.PhoneNumber_Type = 'H'
        AND home.OwnerType = 'C'
        AND home.OwnerRefId = cp.RefId
    WHERE cp.ZoneId = '123123'
)
SELECT
    *
FROM myCTE
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Outer Apply](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
SELECT cp.RefId, W.work, W.work_id, H.home, H.home_id
    FROM Contacts cp
         Outer Apply 
         (
          Select Top 1  work.Id as work_id, work.PhoneNumber  as work
          From    OtherPhoneNumber work 
          Where  work.ZoneId = cp.ZoneId  AND work.PhoneNumber_Type = 'W' AND work.OwnerType = 'C' AND work.OwnerRefId = cp.RefId
         Order By Work.Id Desc
         ) W
        Outer Apply
        (
         Select Top 1  home.Id as home_id, home.PhoneNumber  as Home
         From OtherPhoneNumber home 
         Where home.ZoneId = cp.ZoneId  AND home.PhoneNumber_Type = 'H' AND home.OwnerType = 'C' AND home.OwnerRefId = cp.RefId
        Order By H.Id Desc
        ) H
    WHERE cp.ZoneId = '123123'
```